# Access cookies from LibGDX Applet

Tags: java, applet, libgdx

I am developing a LibGDX applet game and I want to access the cookies set by JavaScript. I can't use `JSObject window = JSObject.getWindow(this);` since the way I build the applet is as following (you may know this).

```
public class MainApplet extends LwjglApplet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public MainApplet() {
        super(new TitansArena(), false);
    }
}
```

How can I access the cookies?

**EDIT:**

I want to access the javascript inside my `TitansArena` class. In order to do this i need to access the applet from `TitansArena` but i can't get a reference to it. I need some way to access the applet inside `TitansArena` so I can create a reference to the window object of the html document.

Comment: Can you explain the "can't use `JSObject`" problems in more detail?  (What/where have you tried it?)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note that attempting to obtain a reference to the `JSObject` usually fails if called from a constructor or `init()`.  It can be obtained in the `start()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the specifics of the `JSObject` API, but in general with Libgdx applications the way you get access from platform independent code (`TitansArena` in this case) out to platform dependent code (`MainApplet` in this case) is to create an interface and pass an instance implementing that interface.  See https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific

Specifically, you could do something like this: create a new interface called `SaveState` with a method `save(String)`.  Add a new static inner class to `MainApplet` (called `AppletSaveState` for example) that implements this interface and pass a new instance of it to the `TitansArena` constructor (add a constructor parameter with the `SaveState` type).  Now your platform independent code can invoke `save` on the object passed into the constructor and then you'll be in the `MainApplet` context where you can use `JSObject` and its methods.

Oi, because of the `super` call, its somewhat annoying to setup.  I think lazily initializing a pointer from the `SaveState` instance back to the `MainApplet` will do it.  Something like:

```
public class MainApplet extends LwjglApplet {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final SaveState saver = new AppletSaveState();

    public MainApplet() {
       super(new TitansArena(saver), false);
       saver.appletContext = this; // fixup saver instance to point necessary context
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is i can't pass this to the constructor. `Cannot refer to 'this' nor 'super' while explicitly invoking a constructor.`